# How do I add .htaccess file in my SharePoint Site

Tags: sharepoint-designer, redirect, seo

Can I use `.htaccess` file for redirecting and other things in SharePoint 2010 site?

If Yes, tell me how.

If No, Please advice me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharepoint runs on Windows not apache, so doesn't use htaccess. .hta files are not supported by sharepoint.

There are other ways to redirecting like following:

You can install and use the URL rewrite module for IIS, which is an extension for IIS Server version >7.

Here are some articles about how to use it and create rewrite rules:

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module